# How to make create a function that renders HTML in Razor?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I just want a way to organize my code in asp.net, such that I can create function block to generate different parts of the cshtml...
The code below doesn't work (invalid expression term '<', th doesn't exist...)

abc.cshtml:

```
@functions {
    public void TableHeaders()
    {
        <th> @property.Name </th>
     }

}
 
<div> 
    @TableHeaders()
</div>
```

So, I've tried extra different options:

1: @helper (The helper directive is not supported)

2: Declaring a Func<string, object (or IHtmlContent)> TableHeaders would return System.Func`2[System.Object,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent]

3: I don't want Html.Raw($@""), it just makes the code smells bad as you can easily miss an html tag

If you have worked with React before, you can easily return a jsx from a function call, would be nice to have similar thing working in Razor page.

Comment: Maybe a `Html Helper Extension`? https://www.foreach.be/blog/create-a-custom-html-helper-in-asp-net-mvc-using-razor?lang=nl

Comment: Creating an Extension class solely for returning an HTML seems like an overkill, eventually there will be tens of Html Helper Extension classes

Comment: No just one, and send a variable with like an Enum with it to get the correct html block.

Comment: @functions interestingly works in the other computer.  Both computer are using .Net Core 3.1.x, will see why that happens

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there with this. The correct syntax is:

```
@functions {
    async Task TableHeaders()
    {
        <th> @property.Name </th>
     }

}
 
<div> 
    @{ await TableHeaders(); }
</div>
```

The lack of documentation around these is painful (IMO)